# execl vs execv with unknown argument size

Tags: c, shell, unix, process, exec

Here is the case: I had to use execl and execv in my project, the problem is if the argument size is unknown but the path is known, how should I use execl ? Or should I use execv everytime instead. What are the differences between them ?

For example if the user enters: gcc a.c -o a.out OR in another line enters ls -l how can I execute them in execl or execv ? ps: I can find path, or the user may enter it.

Another main question is, if I got several paths, how can I seperate the correct path which my command in, should I try in if else case, each of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `execl` when you know the size of the argument list, you use `execv` when you have to construct the argument list dynamically.

I don't understand the second question. But you shouldn't ask two questions in one post in SO. Start another question with your second one, and explain more clearly what you're asking.