# Passing arguments to execl

Tags: unix, posix

I want to create my own pipeline like in Unix terminal (just to practice). It should take applications to execute in quotes like that:

```
pipeline "ls -l" "grep" ....
```

I know that I should use `fork()`, `execl()` (`exec*`) and API to redirect stdin and stdout. But are there any alternatives for `execl` to execute app with arguments using just one argument which includes application path and arguments? Is there a way not to parse manually `ls -l` but pass it as one argument to `execl`?

Comment: There are a lot of questions that are closely related to this on SO.  From the 'related' list: [`execl()` vs `execv()` with unknown argument size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508115/execl-vs-execv-with-unknown-argument-size); there are others in that list that may be relevant and many questions not in that list that are relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only a single command line instead of an argument vector, let the shell do the parsing for you:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", the_command_line, NULL);
```

Of course, don't let untrusted remote user input into this command line. But if you are dealing with untrusted remote user input to begin with, you should try to arrange to pass actual a list of isolated arguments to the target application as per normal usage of `exec[vl]`, not a command line.

Answer (score 3):

Realistically, you can only really use `execl()` when the number of arguments to the command are known at compile time.  In a shell, you'll normally use `execv()` or `execvp()` instead; these can handle an arbitrary number of arguments to the command to be executed.  In theory, you use `execv()` when the path name of the command is given and `execvp()` (which does a PATH-based search for the command) when it isn't.  However, `execvp()` handles the 'path given' case, so simply use `execvp()`.

So, for your `pipeline` command, you'll end up with one child using something equivalent to:

```
char *args_1[] = { "ls", "-l", 0 };
execvp(args_1[0], args_1);
```

The other child will end up using something equivalent to:

```
char *args_2[] = { "grep", "pattern", 0 };
execvp(args_2[0], args_2);
```

Except, of course, that you'll have created those strings from the command line arguments instead of by initialization as shown.  Note that `grep` requires a pattern to search for.

You've still got plumbing issues to resolve.  Make sure you close enough pipe file descriptors.  When you `dup()` or `dup2()` a pipe to standard input or standard output, you close both the file descriptors from the `pipe()` function.